# inserting all datasets from database table into jTable Java

Tags: java, database, swing, user-interface, jtable

i am trying to select all datasets into a jTable (after a button click) from my database.

I tried something like this:

`public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    java.sql.Connection con;
con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lessonstbl","root","");
            String query =" SELECT * FROM lessons";
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);`

```
     try {
            rs.absolute(rowIndex + 1);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: 
                    return rs.getString(1);
                case 1:
                    return rs.getString(2);
                case 2:
                    return rs.getInt(3);
                case 3:
                    return rs.getObject(4).toString();
                case 4:
                    return rs.getObject(5).toString();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
```

..
but that does not work.
Thx all in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can see where is your problem. Please also check whether you get the correct data from the database (for example print them in `System.out`).

Comment: Thx for your answer. That is the only thingI could try I don't know how to code this :(

Comment: To help out I need more information. What are these objects you're trying to get back from database? What are you trying to accomplish with this code? What is the type of the info you wanna feed your JTable with?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
```

It looks to me like you are trying to override the `getValueAt(...)` method of the TableModel. That won't work for a couple of reasons:

1. You are changing the method signature by adding the throws SQLExeption, so you are not overriding the default implementation of the TableModel, but instead creating a new method that is not invoked.
2. It is a bad idea to do an SQL query in the getVaueAt() method. This method should be very effiecient since it is invoked every time a cell in the table needs to be painted.

So the proper solution is to do the SQL query when the table is created and load all the data from the SQL query into the TableModel at the start of your class. This means you will need to iterate through all the row and columns of the `ResultSet` to add the data to the `TableModel`.

Check out the `Table From DataBase Example` found in [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). Or you can search the forum for other examples with the keywords "ResultSet and JTable".